# Getting Mac Docker client to connect to virtualbox via vagrant

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, docker

I am trying to expose dockers tcp ip to my host docker client. I have the following setup

- Virtualbox 4.3.26 r98988
- vagrant 1.7.2
- Mac OSX Mavericks 10.9.5
- Centos 6.6 vagrant box running (docker 1.5.0)
- Docker 1.5 on the host and vagrant box

FYI, I can get to the exposed docker containers just fine in the browser. I have exposed the necessary ports in the VagrantFile

[image]

in /etc/init.d/docker I have set other_args as the following:

`other_args="--insecure-registry 192.168.254.96:5000 -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"`

I have set the following `DOCKER_HOST=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375` on the host and I get the following error:

`FATA[0076] An error occurred trying to connect: Get https://127.0.0.1:2375/v1.17/containers/json: EOF`

If i set the DOCKER_HOST=tcp://172.17.8.101 then i get

`FATA[0076] An error occurred trying to connect: Get https://127.0.0.1:2375/v1.17/containers/json: EOF
I'm not able to run the usual docker ps from the host.`

I tried running netstat -tulpn to see what the virtualbox/vagrant instance was listening to. It seems like 2375 is listening.

[image: netstat -tulpn]

I tried looking at the virtual network settings for that instance
[image]
[image]
[image]

I have a few questions

1. Did I set the tcp connection correctly in /etc/init.d/docker. Should it be the ip that I set in vagrant?
2. Is there a way to check if the docker client is connecting with the mac host?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using https (https://docs.docker.com/articles/https/). After those steps were completed I needed to stop iptables service `/etc/init.d/iptables stop`.